# How to add default value to bootstrap tag select input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap tag plugin](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) and I successfully add some tags to it using this code:

```
$(function () {            
                var data = [{"id":"1","value":"painting-works"},{"id":"2","value":"plumbing-works"},{"id":"3","value":"programming"}];    
                var states = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    local: data
                });
                states.initialize();
                $("#tags").tagsinput({
                    itemValue: 'id',
                    itemText: 'value',
                    allowDuplicates: false,
                    maxTags: 1,    
                    typeaheadjs: {
                        name: "states",
                        displayKey: 'value',
                        source: states.ttAdapter(),
                    },
                    freeInput: true
                });  
});
```

and the input element is

```
<select placeholder=""  class="bootstrap-tagsinput"  id="tags"></select>
```

the tags are added successfully 
[image]

but what I want is to add a default value to the input element when the page is loaded  like this 
[image]

I have tried this code

```
$('#tags').tagsinput('add', 'new');
```

but it only adds a new tag
and I tried to use jQuery

```
$('#tags').val("painting-works");
```

but it didn't work, what should I do?

Comment: Why don't you use "input type text" instead of dropdown? then use : $('#tags').tagsinput('add', 'new');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you are using array of objects as the data, so you need to pass one of the object to `tagsInput` on page load

```
$('#tags').tagsinput('add', {"id":"1","value":"painting-works"});
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgaLjL6c/) with solution